# Объединение 2-х отсортированных массивов в 1 в Java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, слияние

> Реализуйте метод, сливающий два отсортированных по неубыванию массива чисел в один отсортированный в том же порядке массив. Массивы могут быть любой длины, в том числе нулевой.
>
> Предполагается, что вы реализуете алгоритм слияния, имеющий линейную сложность: он будет идти по двум исходным массивам и сразу формировать отсортированный результирующий массив. Так, чтобы сортировка полученного массива при помощи Arrays.sort() уже не требовалась.
>
> Пример ввода: {0, 2, 2} и {1, 3}
> Пример вывода: {0, 1, 2, 2, 3}.

Написала код, но у меня он не работает в случае если в обоих массивах числа отрицательные. Что я делаю не так?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArrays(new int[]{0, 2, 2}, new int[]{1, 3})));
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArrays(new int[]{}, new int[]{})));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArrays(new int[]{-4, -3, -1}, new int[]{-10, -5, -2})));
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArrays(new int[]{}, new int[]{1, 3})));
}

public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    int[] a3 = new int[a1.length + a2.length];

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < a3.length; k++) {
        if ((i > a1.length - 1) || (a1[i] > a2[j])) {
            a3[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        } else if ((j > a2.length - 1) || (a1[i] < a2[j])) {
            a3[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            a3[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return a3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор

```
if ((i > a1.length - 1) || (a1[i] > a2[j]))
```

будет обращаться ко второму массиву, даже если он кончился.

Отделите проверки индексов от сравнения значений.

Проще всего сделать три цикла. В первом основное слияние, еще в двух дописка неиспользованных остатков, если они есть.

```
while ((i < a1.length) && (j < a2.length)) {
  if (a1[i] <= a2[j]) 
    ...
}
while (i < a1.length) {
} 
while (j < a2.length) {
}
```

Comment: попробую, спасибо

Comment: Добрый день, у меня еще 1 вопрос: почему в данном коде указано условие                      
                                                                                                                                                      (index2 >= a2.length || index1 < a1.length && a1[index1] < a2[index2]),                                           
 а именно index2 >= a2.length, это же выражение всегда будет false.

Comment: Пример кода:                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                     
  ``` public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    if (a1 == null)
        return a2;
    if (a2 == null)
        return a1;
    int[] result = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0; ```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (index2 >= a2.length || index1 < a1.length && a1[index1] < a2[index2]) {
            result[i] = a1[index1];
            index1++;
        } else {
            result[i] = a2[index2];
            index2++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Comment: Зачем так наворачивать? Это же невозможно прочитать и легко допустить ошибку. Добавил канонический вариант

Comment: MBo, спасибо большое за ответ ) Хорошего дня!

Answer (score 1):

Объединяем два массива и группируем по количеству дубликатов в карту `TreeMap`. Дополнительная сортировка уже не нужна. Получаем из карты все элементы, вместе с дубликатами, и возвращаем массив:

```java
int[] arr1 = {0, 2, 2};
int[] arr2 = {1, 3};

int[] arr = Stream.of(arr1, arr2)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e,
                TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .flatMapToInt(e ->
                LongStream.range(0, e.getValue()).mapToInt(v -> e.getKey()))
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Давно пользуюсь такой функцией, попробуйте:

```
public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int[] result = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
    int i = 0, j = 0, r = 0;
    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            result[r] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            result[r] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
        r++;
    }
    if (i < arr1.length) {
        System.arraycopy(arr1, i, result, r, (arr1.length - i));
    }
    if (j < arr2.length) {
        System.arraycopy(arr2, j, result, r, (arr2.length - j));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]